# What makes a pre-trained model in pytorch misclassify an image

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

I successfully trained Data Efficient Image Transformer (deit) on cifar-10 dataset with an accuracy of about 95%. However and saved it for later use. I created a separate class to load the model and make inference on just one image. I keep getting different value for prediction every time I run it.

```
import torch
from models.deit import deit_small_patch16_224

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.transforms import transforms as transforms
class_names = ['plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = deit_small_patch16_224(pretrained=True, use_top_n_heads=8, use_patch_outputs=False)

checkpoint = torch.load("./checkpoint/deit224.t7")
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)
model.head = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.head.in_features, out_features=10)
model.eval()


img = Image.open("cats.jpeg")
img_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(img))/255.0
img_tensor = img_tensor.unsqueeze(0).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
# print(img_tensor.shape)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(img_tensor)
    predicted_class = np.argmax(output)
    print(predicted_class)
```

Comment: It looks like you are resetting the linear layer after loading: `model.head = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.head.in_features, out_features=10)
`  In essence you have random weights for classification

Comment: ^ I agree. `load_state_dict` is loading the weights, you then immediately replace a layer in the network with a new (randomly initialized) linear layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,figured out the error. updated code below

```
import torch
from models.deit import deit_small_patch16_224
from torch.utils.data import dataset
import torchvision.datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.transforms import transforms as transforms
class_names = ['plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = deit_small_patch16_224(pretrained=True, use_top_n_heads=8, use_patch_outputs=False)

checkpoint = torch.load("./checkpoint/deit224.t7")
state_dict = checkpoint["model"]
new_state_dict = {}
for key in state_dict:
    new_key = '.'.join(key.split('.')[1:])
    new_state_dict[new_key] = state_dict[key]

model.head = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.head.in_features, out_features=10)
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
model.eval()


img = Image.open("cats.jpeg")
trans = transforms.ToTensor()
# img_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(img, dtype=np.float64))/255.0
img_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(img))/255.0
# img_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(img))

img_tensor = img_tensor.unsqueeze(0).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
# print(img_tensor.shape)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(img_tensor)
    predicted_class = np.argmax(output)
    print(predicted_class)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?